# How to add UIView under a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiwebview

I'm working over blog app, like Medium. And there I present my post in the UIWebView. Now, I want to add UIView under the UIWebView, to show the author of the post and I want to show it when user scrolls the post and in the end of the post to show this UIView. But I do not know how to show it.

My UIWebView has 4 constraints(top, bottom, left, right = 0). So, how can I put it under the UIWebView and show when user scrolls to the end of a post?

Any suggestions or advices?

Comment: Are you asking to have a a UIView under the webview or to appear as part of the webview at the bottom? I don't think the second one is easily doable.

Comment: Have you tried placing both inside a UIScrollView? Doing it this way would cause problems with which view interprets the scroll, so you'd have to do some fiddling with enabling and disabling scroll on the UIWebView and UIScrollView at the appropriate times -- it may end up being a very fragile approach but theoretically it may be able to be done.